# How to check if Column name exists in database. In Mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a list of column names, that may or may not be in a specific MySQL database

Is it possible to query the DB to see if a column name exists? When i do not know which table it might be in?

If yes, how would I do so?

**This question has an answer that assumes i know which table it is in. I do not**
[MySQL: How to create Column if not exists?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/169458/mysql-how-to-create-column-if-not-exists)

**this answer is close, but also assumes i know exactly where each column is** (i am trying to automate insertion, and the column names that exist may be different from the column names i will insert in the future, but contain the same data)
[How to select specific rows if a column exists or all rows if a column doesn't](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44871/how-to-select-specific-rows-if-a-column-exists-or-all-rows-if-a-column-doesnt)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to select specific rows if a column exists or all rows if a column doesn't](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/44871/how-to-select-specific-rows-if-a-column-exists-or-all-rows-if-a-column-doesnt)

Comment: Maybe. is there a way to get only column names from the information schema?

Comment: Yes you can, but *why* don't you know what the table structures are?  To me, this sounds like trying to Reverse Engineer someone else's database.  Questionable at best.

Comment: i do, there are just so many of them, and they arent organized according to the way my client wants to insert data. 
i'm trying to get data from a csv file and send it to the database. some of the headers of the spreadsheet are existing column names in the db, and some are not. i am trying to automate inserting data to the ones that exist, without having to look into every table and do it manually

Answer (score 0):

thanks to mustaccio for pointing out the other question that explains the Information_schema.

with MySql you would query
`SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;`
and get a list of all columns

i would add that it gives a list of **ALL** column names, even the ones generated by MySql

Comment: And if you add `...where column_name in ('COLUMNS','IWANT','TOFIND')` it will return just the columns you are interested in, won't it?

Comment: i will try that

Answer (score 0):

As you noted you can use the Information_Schema, and then know the tables the columns are part of as well:

```
SELECT *
    FROM   information_schema.columns
    LEFT JOIN information_schema.tables
          ON columns.table_name = tables.table_name 
         AND columns.table_catalog = tables.table_catalog`
```

SQL Fiddle Link:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb/254846